# Erro na linguagem do Python

Tags: python

Eu sou novo no Python, está dando esse erro que existe na imagem.

http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/sem_titulo-png--8888

Oque posso fazer para resolver ?

Comment: Berdam, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Por favor, tente não usar imagens externas ao site, assim como postar o código na própria pergunta. Se puder, edite a pergunta e coloque o código na mesma usando a formatação adequada. Isso irá facilitar ao pessoal te ajudar. Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, use `==` para comparar variáveis e não `=`, que é atribuição.

Segundo, sobre o `else` posterior, transforme-o num `elif` ou acrescente um `:` (dois pontos)  e remova as condições.

Terceiro, cuidado com o validador do Eclipse, algumas vezes ele pode se confundir ou ficar "defasado" e mostrar o erro no lugar errado ou então um erro já corrigido.

Answer (score 1):

Não sou um conhecedor da linguagem phyton, mas sou um entusiasta em programação que adora conhecer novas linguagens e novos paradigmas de linguagem.... pelo que dei uma lida na web, o operador lógico de igualdade no phyton é `==` e não `=` como na linha de código de erro que você mostrou.... tenta ver se não é isso

O operador lógico `=` seria "atribuição" como em outras linguagens de programação